# Why do I get "Users without post commenting privilege can't edit auto-generated comments" when trying to edit my non-auto-generated comment?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, edits, privileges

I posted a comment on an answer to my question, then shortly after wanted to improve the formatting of the comment. I clicked the `Edit` icon next to the comment, made my changes and then when I tried to save them I was shown a red error message saying:

> Users without post commenting privilege can't edit auto-generated comments

I have read [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and not found an answer there.

Could it be that I began the editing inside the 5 minute window allowed for editing but was outside that window by the time I clicked save? If so, why is the error message not more appropriate?

The comment in question is: [Why does Ctrl-Down Arrow in Excel take me to row 1048576?](https://superuser.com/questions/1158730/why-does-ctrl-down-arrow-in-excel-take-me-to-row-1048576#comment1668865_1158732)

Comment: Can you show the example of this comment?

Comment: Sorry, yes - it was this one: http://superuser.com/questions/1158730/why-does-ctrl-down-arrow-in-excel-take-me-to-row-1048576#comment1668865_1158732

Comment: Yes, looks like you missed the edit window. You can always comment on your own questions and on their answers so it is the wrong error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wasn't just a wrong message, there was actually a bug that prevented low reputation users from editing their comments, regardless of the edit window time. It is fixed now.